# Find the osculating plane and the curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm asked to find the osculating plane and the curvature of the curve

$r(t)=(a\cos(t)+b\sin(t),\, a\sin(t)+b\cos(t),\, c\sin(2t)),\, t\in \mathbb{R}.$

To find the osculating plane, first I tried to compute the binormal vector using the formula

$$B(t)=\dfrac{r'(t)\times r''(t)}{||r'(t)\times r''(t)||}\,,$$
but the result got very long. Also, the point on which I am supposed to find the osculating plane is not given.

For the curvature, I have a similar problem, since I'm trying to use the formula

$$\kappa=\dfrac{||r'(t)\times r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}.$$

I have no idea whether I'm on the right track. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't know if the calculation is any easier, but have you considered trying to find the Frenet-Serret frame?